# How to reset the off set value after 2000 records

Tags: apex, query

I have aura component which fetch the records And I have a Object that has 2100 records Now I have to navigate to the last record page but it is not possible because of offset limit so how to overcome from that ..

```
@AuraEnabled
public static WrapperClass getRecords(List<String> selectedFields,String selectedObject,Integer PageSize,String FieldValue,String SortDir,Integer PageNumber,String recId){
    WrapperClass wc = new WrapperClass();
    System.debug('The records id is ' + recId);
    FieldValue = FieldValue == '' ? 'Id' : FieldValue;
    String query = 'SELECT '+String.join(selectedFields,',')+' FROM '+selectedObject;
    Integer offsetsize = (PageNumber - 1) * PageSize;
    if(offsetsize > 2000){
        if(String.isNotBlank(recId)) {
            recId = String.valueOf(recId);
            query += ' WHERE ID >: recId ';
        }   
    }
    query += ' ORDER BY '+FieldValue+' '+SortDir+' NULLS LAST';
    if(PageSize != null && Integer.valueOf(PageSize) > 0) {
        PageSize = Integer.valueOf(PageSize);
        query += ' Limit '+PageSize;
    }
    query+= ' OFFSET ' + offsetsize;
    System.debug('The Final Query Is ::' + query);
    wc.sObjList =  Database.query(query);
    wc.totalRecordsCount =  Database.countQuery('SELECT Count() from ' + selectedObject);
    return wc;
}
public class WrapperClass{
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<sObject> sObjList;
    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer totalRecordsCount;
    
    
}
```